# Accessing functions in external folders to public_html in node.js/express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I cannot access JavaScript code outside the public_html folder defined by express.js in Node.js. I was able to do so when I used PHP and Apache instead of Node.js and NGINX. I could call a PHP function in an external file to public_html. However, the web visitors did not have access to the external folders to public_html in the case of PHP/Apache (which the web host had configured). I want to achieve the same with Node.js/express.j and NGINX. That is, from inside public_html calling functions in js files that are external to public_html and the web visitors cannot access them.

My Node.js relevant code block:

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express()
// ...
app.use(express.static('public_html'))
```

Referencing a library in d3 folder in */home/public_html/d3* works:

(In the index.html file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
```

Referencing a library in d3 folder external to public_html in */home/d3* does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course, `express.static` defines something like root for the application. These files are accessible by anyone. If `../d3/d3.js` would work, everyone could access all of your server.

Comment: If you want to access something outside `public_html` you can create an alias. However, whatever you described that worked for PHP is [Path Traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) vulnerability, you better not have such a thing in your application. If the client can do `../d3/d3.js` what keeps them not doing `../../../../etc/passwd` ? An attacker can easily expose private parts of your server.

Comment: You are comparing PHP which runs on the server to a html which runs in the users's browser.

Comment: The good thing with PHP was that instead of a .html file, I could use .php files that contained the HTML code. Node.js has an npm package for d3.js, but then as you say, HTML runs on the client-side and PHP or node.js on the server-side. What is the point of an npm package for D3.js? I liked EJS as a templating language substitute for a while. Still, it causes some limitations in developing single-page websites using fetch API for live updates of data. I'd rather stay with vanilla JS. D3.js is a necessary exception.